# Setting width in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Sorry, I'm sure I'm missing something very simple!

I have some HTML structured like this:

```
<div class="main_image">
   <a href="IMGLINK">
      <img src="IMGLINK" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 4350px) 100vw, 4350px" width="4350" height="2401">
   </a>
   <label>caption caption caption</label>
</div>
```

And some javascript like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    newWidth = $(".main_image .wp-post-image").width(); 
    $(".wp-post-image").parent(".main_image").css("width", newWidth);
});
```

The intent behind this is to make sure that the `<label>` doesn't overflow the width of the space allotted for the featured image.

For some reason, this css setting simply doesn't work. (I also tried with other properties, like `display: none`, so I know it's not an issue with width specifically.) What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery documentation:

> [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/): Get the parent of each element in the current set of
> matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

In your case **".main_image"** is a grandfather, hence you need to change **parent()**  with [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

The snippet:

```js
newWidth = $(".main_image .wp-post-image").width(); 
$(".wp-post-image").parent(".main_image").css("width", newWidth);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="main_image">
    <a href="IMGLINK">
        <img src="IMGLINK" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 4350px) 100vw, 4350px" width="4350" height="2401">
    </a>
    <label>caption caption caption</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually still doesn't work - the image being wrapped in a link is a recent change but the problem existed before that.

Comment: @user8539669 ok, please add a valid image, create a snippet in order to reproduce the issue

Comment: hm, well, I fiddled with some other parts after using closest instead of parent and it seems to be sorted, so thanks!